# Python requests response with no status_code

Tags: python, json, django, oauth-2.0

Using Oauth2 through rauth in a Django project, I am able to connect to a custom API. Once the user is logged in via an access token, the API documentation states that I can get user information by sending a request with a specific header.

I am able to send the request with the Requests Python library, but I just cannot find how to process the response, as the api's response allegedly is a simple json file. Django raises an AttributeError as the response has no status_code attribute :

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  230.             response = self.apply_response_fixes(request, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in apply_response_fixes
  277.             response = func(request, response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/utils.py" in conditional_content_removal
  30.     if 100 <= response.status_code < 200 or response.status_code in (204, 304):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /complete/myecp
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

When I inspect the response in the local variables, it's indeed json formatted, with a 'X-Frame-Options' key and a list of keys with user information :

```
    {'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
     ...
     u'gender': u'M',
     u'id': 22943,
     ...
}
```

Any idea about how I can retrieve this response properly?

Here's the request in my view :

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token} 
r = requests.get('https://the.url', headers=headers)
user_data = r.content
```

Comment: This error is being produced by Django itself, not your API request. You should show your view; I suspect that you are simply returning the dict from your view, whereas you should be returning an HttpResponse.

Comment: The end of my view was redirecting to another url, but returning an HttpResponse with my user_data actually displays the data without the error. I still don't really understand why the error is not showing anymore, but thanks a lot !